# What does header/impl keyword mean in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Just moments ago when I was exploring the Kotlin github repo, I found something interesting: Kotlin now seems to have a header keyword.

[CollectionsH.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/be95f66b1343af2a4df2fd022d1ddd6000d5a017/libraries/stdlib/common/src/kotlin/CollectionsH.kt):

```
 open header class ArrayList<E> : MutableList<E> {

 //...

 header inline fun <reified T> Array<out T>?.orEmpty(): Array<out T>
```

What does it mean? Is it some public available feature or a internal feature to help stdlib development?

---

EDIT: There seems to be a `impl` keyword that work in conjunction with header. What's that?

Comment: This keyword is related to multi-platform projects, but this functionality has been neither released nor announced and is currently an internal feature.

Comment: @hotkey are you aware of any examples of the feature being used?

Comment: @spierce7, I don't know of any usage outside the Kotlin project itself.

Comment: @hotkey Here's an example of a multiplatform app made by Jetbrains: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app

Comment: @Aro, indeed, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## UPDATE 2:

Multiplatform project support has been released.

- [Link to the announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/11/kotlin-1-2-released/)
- [Multiplatform application for KotlinConf 2017](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app)

## UPDATE 1:

The `impl` and `header` keywords have been replaced by `actual` and `expect` in the preview release of multiplatform projects for Kotlin.

The official documentation can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) or at this
GitHub [permalink](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/blob/b056703475e9a7e586c588d634a23b36132e0620/pages/docs/reference/multiplatform.md)

---

It was talked about in [this video](https://vimeo.com/215556547#t=868s) at 14:28.

From the [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/abreslav/future-of-kotlin-how-agile-can-language-development-be):
[image: Slide #14]

Basically, `header` will be used when writing interfaces for modules that work across multiple platforms (JVM, JS, and Native). The`impl` keyword will be used when writing an implementation for a specific platform.

Comment: These should be all one need to know about `header` and `impl` keyword`. Thanks for digging that out.