# What does `impl` mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I didn't find any explanation in the reference, but when I type `impl` in IntelliJ IDEA, I get an error:

[image]

It seems that it's treated as a reserved word, but what's it for?
I tried putting many kinds of stuffs after `impl` but I get the error every time.

Update: It's renamed to `expect` after Kotlin 1.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's for future multiplatform project support, and it's the pair of the `header` keyword which @hotkey explained in their comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698001/what-does-header-keyword-mean-in-kotlin#comment72518332_42698001). It appeared in one of Andrey Breslav's presentations which you can find [here](https://vimeo.com/215556547#t=865s), this specific topic starts at the 14:25 mark.

To sum it up briefly, the basic idea he presents is that you could have a common module shared between your platforms, in which there are some functions that are declared but not implemented, and are marked with the `header` keyword. Then, for the different platforms (JVM, JS, etc) you could have separate modules that implement these functions in platform specific ways - these actual implementations are where the `impl` keyword would be used.

[image: His slide about it]

He says that this whole system is just an internal prototype for now, so this presentation is probably all the public info we have about it. I'd also be interested in more details about this mechanism though :)

---

Update: as of the [Kotlin 1.2 Beta](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/09/kotlin-1-2-beta-is-out/), these keywords have been now replaced with `expect` and `actual`.